# Redirect to another directory

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

My site is almost up and running, but in the original code there are, for example `img src="/design/pic1.png"` and so one. On the real server, there is a must dir, `web`, so the new paths should be `img src="web/design/pic1.png"` but I don't want to rewrite all paths.
Is there another option?

Comment: Even if you have the server rewrite all those paths to the newer version, that should only be a temporary fix, and you shouldn't be referring to paths that don't exist just because you don't want to go and change them. Do the right thing and use a good editor that can do search & replace with regular expressions and just replace the paths with the correct ones. (Also, I find it odd that within your website's directory you have a "web" folder—seems redundant to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your set up, one approach would be to have a constant that dictates your base path which is dependant on your environment.

For example, suppose in your development environment you're happy to put all images in `$WEB_ROOT . "/design/"`, but on your production environment it's `$WEB_ROOT . "/web/design/"`, then you might end up with something like this:

```
<?php

    // initialise stuff for development
    if(ENVIRONMENT == ENV_DEV) {

        define("BASE_PATH", "/");

    // initialise stuff for production 
    } elseif(ENVIRONMENT == ENV_PROD) {

        define("BASE_PATH", "/web");

    }

?>
```

Then, in your HTML, you could use this `BASE_PATH` constant like so:

```
<img src="<?=BASE_PATH;?>/design/pic1.png" />
```

How you decide what is `ENV_DEV` and `ENV_PROD` in this example, is entirely up to you.

One approach would be to detect it based on the domain (using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, which [has some caveats](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host)).

Another approach would be to initialise this in your web configuration. Suppose you're using Apache2, you might use the `SetEnv` directive.

In your `httpd.conf`:

```
SetEnv MY_ENVIRONMENT DEV
```

Which you can access in PHP using:

```
<?php

    $_SERVER['MY_ENVIRONMENT'];

    // or...

    getenv("MY_ENVIRONMENT");

?>
```

Comment: thats great, and how about files in .css files?

Comment: That's a tricky one. I tend to place images that are related to CSS files *relative* to the CSS directory. So, if I have `$WEB_ROOT/css/style.css`, I'll create `$WEB_ROOT/css/images/`, and then reference the image in CSS with a relative path, e.g. `images/foo.png`, rather than `/something/something/css/images/foo.png`. Alternatively, if you know that your CSS directory is always one level away from your web-root, you can do `../images/foo.png`.